# sql insertion of a picture into table with sql dynamique script into a stored procedure with a path in parametre

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

1-i have a script that inserts an image into a sql server table with a dynamic sql script but that would like to become a stored process with as a parameter entered a path that designates a photo but it does not work

here is the dynamic sql script:

```
insert into cliente (nom_cli,pic_cli) 
select 'tarik' , bulkcolumn
from openrowset (bulk 'C:\Users\salma\Desktop\tarik zahraoui.jpg' , 
 single_blob)as pic_cli
```

here the stored procedure

```
 create procedure [dbo].[sp_doStuff] (@nom_cliente nvarchar(4000) , 
  @path_in nchar(265))
 as
 begin
  declare @img nvarchar(4000);
  declare @nom_cli nvarchar(4000) ;
  declare @sql nvarchar(4000);
  declare @path nvarchar(4000);
  set @sql='insert into cliente (nom_cli,pic_cli)  select ' + @nom_cli +  ', 
  bulkcolumn
  from openrowset(bulk ''' + (@path) + ''' , single_blob) as pic_cli'
  execute sp_executesql @sql,@path=@path_in,@nom_cli=@nom_cliente
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are not using the parameters in the request, you are using the unassigned internal ones building the dynamic sql.
Also, set quotes around the @nom_cliente parameter. Now you are selecting a column named as @nom_cliente.
I would also recommend to use @params
Try this to see the difference for between quotes around @nom_cliente.

```
declare @nom_cli nvarchar(20) = 'tarik', @path nvarchar(20) ='C:\Users\salma\Desktop\tarik zahraoui.jpg';
declare @sql nvarchar(4000);

set @sql = 'insert into cliente (nom_cli,pic_cli)  select ' + @nom_cli +  ', bulkcolumn from openrowset(bulk ''' + (@path) + ''' , single_blob) as pic_cli';
select @sql;
set @sql = 'insert into cliente (nom_cli,pic_cli) select ''' + @nom_cli +''' , bulkcolumn from openrowset (bulk ''' + @path + ''' ,  single_blob)as pic_cli';
select @sql;
```

As for the procedure, maybe something like this.

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_doStuff] (@nom_cli nvarchar(4000), @path nchar(265))
as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(4000), @params nvarchar(4000);         

    set @sql='insert into cliente (nom_cli,pic_cli)  select ''' + @nom_cli +  ''', 
          bulkcolumn
          from openrowset(bulk ''' + (@path) + ''' , single_blob) as pic_cli';

    set @params = N'@nom_cli NVARCHAR(4000), @path NVARCHAR(256)';

    execute sp_executesql @sql,@params, @path=@path,@nom_cli=@nom_cli;
end;
```

I haven't tested this one since I can't do that at the moment, but it should at least give you an idea about the next step.

Comment: tnx  i will test this one and i will reply .

Comment: Chargement en masse impossible car le fichier "C:\Users\salma\Desktop\tarik zahraoui.jpg   *

Comment: Is there a 'est impossible à/ne peut pas être ouvrir/ouvert' after the path?

Might be an execution rights issure. 
Va voir ces page
[link](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d739201/bases-donnees/ms-sql-server/administration/probleme-droits-d-execution-bulk-insert/)
[link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7b87d35f-7b08-4727-9544-8dd7035c5e87/cannot-bulk-load-because-the-file-could-not-be-opened-operating-system-error-code-5access-is?forum=sqldataaccess)